# Approximation of PI for a Sphere

Tags: python-3.x

Perform the Monte Carlo approximation but using a sphere, so that you use X, Y and Z variables now.
What is the probability expression for your estimate of Pi for this three-dimensional case? What do you get for N = 1000000 samples?
Here is my code : I get 2.096864 for circle radius 1. I am expecting the value closer to PI correct ?

```
import numpy as np
np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=3)
Pi = 4*np.arctan(1)
def approximate_pi(number_of_throws):
    hits = 0
    for i in range(number_of_throws):
        x, y ,z = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=3)
        r = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)
        hits = hits + 1*(r < 1)
    return hits/number_of_throws*4
a = [1000000]
y = [approximate_pi(i) for i in a]
print(y)
```

Comment: Hint: the volume of a sphere is not pi/4

Comment: Probably has to do with your "return" statement. With a circle inscribed inside a square, the proportion of areas is Pi/4. What the proportion of a sphere inscribed inside a cube?

Comment: Vol is 4/3 pi*r^3. Then the approximation is: pi_approx = 6 * inside / n.    
 Changing :                                                                                                        
                  return hits/number_of_throws*6                                                  
 gives pi value closer to pi.